# How to return the number of unique values by category using crossfilter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique, crossfilter

Below I take the given array and create a dimension for Category. I then use group() and reduceCount() in order to get the count within Category. However, I'd like to get the unique unique count for the category instead of simply the count.

Below, A has 2 unique IDs, B has 4 unique IDs, and C has 5 unique IDs.

```
var data = [{
    Category: "A",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "4"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "4"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "5"
}];
```

The following shows the unique counts of crossfilter

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data); 

var XDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.Category;
});
var YDimension = XDimension.group().reduceCount(function (d) {
    return d.Category;
});
```

It returns this

```
"[object Object](3) = [
    {"key":"B","value":8},
        {"key":"C","value":5},
        {"key":"A","value":5}
    ]"
```

but I'd like it to return this:

```
"[object Object](3) = [
    {"key":"B","value":4},
    {"key":"C","value":5},
    {"key":"A","value":2}
]"
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a custom reducer to track what values in the ID property you've seen before. You can do this yourself or you could use a library like [reductio](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio). There is an example of how to do this in the readme. I'm calling it "exception aggregation".

Comment: My main issue is that I need to feed it into DC as a dimension

Comment: What do you mean by that? The output you show above looks like the result of group.all(). If you want to change the way the group counting works in this way, you'll need to use a custom grouping. Reductio is a library for doing custom Crossfilter groupings that does what you want, or you can do it yourself. There are examples in the Crossfilter documentation.